# How to open a (CSV) file in oracle and save it in UTF-8 format if it is in another formats

Tags: oracle, csv, unicode, utf-8, extended-ascii

Can anyone please advise me on the below issue.
I have an oracle program which will take a .CSV file as the input and will process it. We are now facing an issue that when there is an ***extended ASCII character*** appear in the input file, its trimming the next letter after that special character.

We are using the File utility function `Utl_File.Fopen_Nchar()` to open the file and `Utl_File.Get_Line_Nchar()` for reading the characters in the file. The program is written in such a way that it should handle multiple languages(Unicode characters) in the input file.

In the analysis its found that when the character encoding of the CSV file is UTF-8 its processing the file successfully even when extended ASCII characters as well as Unicode characters are there. But some times we are getting the file in ***1252 (ANSI - Latin I)*** format which makes the trimming problem for extended ASCII characters.

So is there any way to handle this issue? Can we open a (CSV) file in oracle and save it in ***UTF-8 format*** if it's in any another formats?
Please let me know if any more info is needed.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: you can try dbms_lob, it can read file into blob and convert it into clob with specific charset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you don't know in which encoding your CSV file is saved then it is not possible to determine any conversion either. You would screw up your CSV file.

What do you mean by "1252 (ANSI - Latin I)"?
Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1 are not equal, see the difference here: [ISO 8859-1 vs. ISO 8859-15 vs. Windows-1252 vs. Unicode](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#ISO_8859-1_vs._ISO_8859-15_vs._Windows-1252_vs._Unicode)
(Sorry for posting the German Wikipedia, however the English version does not show such a nice table)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `fix_latin` command-line tool convert a file from an unknown mixture of ASCII / Latin-1 / CP1251 / UTF8 into UTF8:

```
fix_latin < input.csv > output.csv
```

The `fix_latin` utility is a simple Perl script which is shipped with the [Encoding::FixLatin](https://metacpan.org/release/Encoding-FixLatin) module on CPAN.